# Buscar valores de un diccionario en un JSON y sumarlos

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

Tengo 2 ficheros txt. 1 es un diccionario con termino, valor y tengo otro fichero con un json que simula una lista de tweets.

Tengo que buscar los términos del diccionario en el json y si encuentra el término, que añada el valor a una variable que he asignado antes como 0.

La primera parte ya la tengo con el código:

```
Sentimiento = open("Sentimientos.txt")
Valores = {}
for linea in Sentimiento:
    termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
    Valores[termino] = int(valor)
```

y también consigo que me enumere los términos que encuentra en el json con el código:

```
Tweets = open("salida_tweets.txt",'r')
for i,linea in enumerate(Tweets):
    for Sentimiento in Valores.keys():
        if Sentimiento in linea:
            print("Se ha encontrado {} en el tweet de la linea {}".format(Sentimiento,i))
```

Lo que realmente necesitaría es recorrer Tweets buscando algun termino del primer txt (`Sentimientos`). Si encuentra algún término, que devuelva el valor del término y si no, que muestre 0 para dicho tweet.

Y al final del todo que devuelva la suma de los términos que sí encuentre.

¿Alguna idea de por dónde meterle mano? Supongo debo modificar el código que llevo y hacer un `if: else:` y después usar `numpy` para sumar los valores. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Estaría bien  añadir los dos ficheros para poder ayudarte lo máximo posible.

Comment: Aunque las líneas que lees de `salida_tweets.txt` probablemente sean JSON, en el fondo lo que hace tu programa es buscar palabras dentro de un string (la línea leida). En ese sentido creo que el título de la pregunta y la etiqueta `json` pueden inducir a confusión. A menos que realmente necesites procesar el contenido json "bien" (es decir, buscar las palabras no en las líneas del fichero, sino en ciertos campos json de lo que el fichero contiene) en cuyo caso el código de ejemplo es erróneo, así como la respuesta que yo proporcioné.

Comment: Por favor, aclara si el fichero del que lees los tweets simplemente contiene un tweet por línea, sin estructura, o si contiene JSON. Si es lo primero ¿dónde está el json en este problema? Optaría por cambiar el título de la pregunta. Si es lo segundo ¿seguro que procesarlo línea a línea es lo correcto? ¿No habría que tener en cuenta la estructura de ese JSON? ¿Puedes proporcionar un ejemplo de lo que contiene `salida_tweet.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí correctamente lo que pedías, el código siguiente sería la respuesta. He renombrado algunas de tus variables para seguir los convenios típicos de Python, según los cuales la inicial en mayúscula se reserva para nombres de clases (este convenio y otros están especificados en el [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), de la que hay una [traducción](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf) no oficial al español).

```py
sentimiento = open("Sentimientos.txt")
valores = {}
for linea in sentimiento:
    termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
    valores[termino] = int(valor)

tweets = open("salida_tweets.txt",'r')
for i, linea in enumerate(tweets):
    total = 0
    for sentimiento, valor in valores.items():
        if sentimiento in linea:
            print("Se ha encontrado {} en el tweet de la linea {} (valor={})"
                  .format(sentimiento, i, valor))
            total += valor
    print("El tweet de la línea {} tiene un valor de {}".format(i, total))
```

Este código calcula la suma de valores de todos los sentimientos encontrados en cada tweet, que creo que es lo que pedías.

## Actualización

Una vez el OP ha suministrado un ejemplo del contenido del archivo `salida_tweets.txt` se ve que dicho contenido consiste en un tweet por línea, pero cada tweet es una estructura JSON, no una simple cadena de texto.

Copio aquí parte del contenido suministrado por el OP:

```
{"delete":{"status":{"id":294512601600258048,"id_str":"294512601600258048","user_id":90681582,"user_id_str":"90681582"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494083"}}
{"created_at":"Wed Sep 10 17:01:33 +0000 2014","id":509748524897292288,"id_str":"509748524897292288","text":"@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":509748106015948800,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"509748106015948800","in_reply_to_user_id":242563886,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"242563886","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Brenamae_","user":{"id":175160659,"id_str":"175160659","name":"Butterfly","screen_name":"VanessaLilyWan","location":"Canada, Montreal","url":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/vanessalilywan","description":"British youtubers. 'Nuff said.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":118,"friends_count":180,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":319,"statuses_count":10221,"created_at":"Thu Aug 05 20:03:16 +0000 2010","utc_offset":-36000,"time_zone":"Hawaii","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"B2DFDA","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"93A644","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"FFFFFF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/175160659\/1404361640","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Brenamae_","name":"I-G-G-Bye","id":242563886,"id_str":"242563886","indices":[0,10]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1410368493668"}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":204951917716189185,"id_str":"204951917716189185","user_id":496152394,"user_id_str":"496152394"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494071"}}
```

Muchas de las líneas de este ejemplo no parecen "verdaderos" tweets, pues no contienen el campo `"text"`. De hecho, la única línea que parece un tweet verdadero es la que comienza por `{"created_at"...` Las restantes parecen más bien acciones de borrado.

Con esta nueva información, no creo que el enfoque inicial de buscar ciertas palabras (sentimientos) en cada línea sea lo más indicado. Pensemos por ejemplo que una de las palabra-clave a buscar es `"time"`. Esta palabra apareec en todas las líneas porque todos los tweets contienen en su JSON la hora a que fueron emitidos en un campo llamado `"time"`. Pero entiendo que lo que se busca es sólo los tweets que usen la palabra `"time"` como parte del mensaje del tweet, y no como parte del JSON completo.

Por otro lado, tal como estaba el código, no se estaba teniendo en cuenta que un sentimiento debe ser encontrado aún si ha sido escrito en mayúsculas en el Tweet. Por ejemplo, el único Tweet que contiene texto (la segunda línea del ejemplo), tiene el siguiente texto:

```
@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE
```

que está todo en mayúsculas (y además, mira qué casualidad, usa la palabra TIME de que mencioné antes).

Por tanto, una forma correcta de abordar el problema en mi opinión sería:

1. Leer cada línea del fichero de tweeets
2. Parsear el json contenido en esa línea para obtener un diccionario python
3. Mirar si ese diccionario contiene el campo `text`. Si no, ignorar la línea ya que no es un "verdadero" tweet.
4. Quedarse con el campo `text, pasarlo a minúsculas y usarlo para buscar en él los sentimientos y computar las correspondientes puntuaciones.

Todo eso lo hace el siguiente código, en el que he suministrado los contenidos de unos ficheros de ejemplo como cadenas, para que cualquiera pueda probarlo y ver que funciona aún sin disponer de los ficheros. Sólo queda cambiar los `io.IOString()` por `open()` de los correspondientes ficheros para que funcione sobre ficheros en vez de cadenas.

```py
contenido_tweets = r'''
{"delete":{"status":{"id":294512601600258048,"id_str":"294512601600258048","user_id":90681582,"user_id_str":"90681582"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494083"}}
{"created_at":"Wed Sep 10 17:01:33 +0000 2014","id":509748524897292288,"id_str":"509748524897292288","text":"@Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ONE LAST TIME: GO AWHALE","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":509748106015948800,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"509748106015948800","in_reply_to_user_id":242563886,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"242563886","in_reply_to_screen_name":"Brenamae_","user":{"id":175160659,"id_str":"175160659","name":"Butterfly","screen_name":"VanessaLilyWan","location":"Canada, Montreal","url":"http:\/\/instagram.com\/vanessalilywan","description":"British youtubers. 'Nuff said.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":118,"friends_count":180,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":319,"statuses_count":10221,"created_at":"Thu Aug 05 20:03:16 +0000 2010","utc_offset":-36000,"time_zone":"Hawaii","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"B2DFDA","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme13\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"93A644","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"FFFFFF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/470701406245376000\/2aXDrauR_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/175160659\/1404361640","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Brenamae_","name":"I-G-G-Bye","id":242563886,"id_str":"242563886","indices":[0,10]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1410368493668"}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":204951917716189185,"id_str":"204951917716189185","user_id":496152394,"user_id_str":"496152394"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494071"}}
{"delete":{"status":{"id":509733211497193473,"id_str":"509733211497193473","user_id":2328935617,"user_id_str":"2328935617"},"timestamp_ms":"1410368494165"}}
'''

contenido_sentimientos = '''
time\t5
slap\t2
whale\t3
'''

# ------------------------
import io
import json

sentimiento = io.StringIO(contenido_sentimientos)
valores = {}
for linea in sentimiento:
    linea = linea.strip()
    if not linea:
      continue      # Saltarse lineas en blanco
    termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
    valores[termino.lower()] = int(valor)

tweets = io.StringIO(contenido_tweets)
for i, linea in enumerate(tweets):
    total = 0
    linea = linea.strip()
    if not linea:
      continue     # Saltarse lineas vacias

    # Convertir el JSON de la línea a un diccionario python
    data = json.loads(linea)
    if "text" not in linea:
      continue     # Saltarse líneas que no tengan un tweet
    for sentimiento, valor in valores.items():
        if sentimiento in data["text"].lower():
            print("Se ha encontrado {} en el tweet de la linea {} (valor={})"
                  .format(sentimiento, i, valor))
            total += valor
    print("El tweet de la línea {} tiene un valor de {}".format(i, total))
```

El resultado que sale por pantalla es:

> Se ha encontrado time en el tweet de la linea 2 (valor=5)
>   Se ha encontrado slap en el tweet de la linea 2 (valor=2)
>   Se ha encontrado whale en el tweet de la linea 2 (valor=3)
>   El tweet de la línea 2 tiene un valor de 10

Comment: Muchas gracias JLDiaz! Así tendría una parte. La otra era recorrer cada tweet y si aparece un término que devuelva su valor y sino que escriba 0. Supongo con un if else es suficiente. No??