# Calcular la media aritmética de terminos de un diccionario que no se encuentran en un json

Tags: json, numpy, diccionarios

Estoy intentando hacer el siguiente código: Cómo en el ejercicio anterior ([Buscar valores de un diccionario en un JSON y sumarlos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140815/buscar-valores-de-un-diccionario-en-un-json-y-sumarlos)) tengo 2 ficheros, un diccionario y un json. Ahora consiste en buscar los términos del diccionario en el json y si no lo encuentra, que calcule la media aritmética de los valores que contienen dichos términos. Estoy intentando hacerlo con el siguiente código pero aunque consigo saber que valores no están dentro del json, luego no consigo hacer la media aritmética de los valores ya que no consigo acceder a ellos. Previamente a esta manera de proceder a intentando hacer un for xxx not in xxx: para que recorra el json buscando estos términos pero no lo he conseguido. Os el código que estoy utilizando para vuestros comentarios al respecto. También he intentado utilizar numpy.

```
#creamos el diccionario con los terminos a buscar en el json
sentimientos = open('Sentimiento.txt') 
Valores = {} 
for linea in sentimientos: termino, valor = linea.split("\t") 
Valores [termino] = int(valor) 
r = Valores.items()

#Buscamos los valores que están dentro de tweets
tweets = open("salida_tweets.txt",'r') 
for i, linea in enumerate(tweets): 
total = 0 for sentimientos, valor in Valores.items(): 
if sentimientos in linea: 
print(sentimientos, valor) 
w = {sentimientos, valor} 

#restamos ambas variable para obtener los terminos que queremos hacer la media
resta = r - w
```

He intentado utilizar append para añadir los valores encontrado a una variable, con numpy utilizar np.median() pero me falta cómo conseguir acceder a los valores.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Pásanos el ejercicio anterior

Comment: Buenas tardes, el enlace al ejercicio anterior estaba arriba pero lo vuelvo a copiar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140815/buscar-valores-de-un-diccionario-en-un-json-y-sumarlos